# Can diffeomorphisms only be defined on real manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, definition, diffeomorphism

I am looking at definitions of diffeomorphisms. In (Marathe, 2010) the author keeps the chapter (chap 3) on manifolds fairly general - except when defining diffeomorphims and differential maps, between manifolds. In this case they restrict their attention to real differentiable manifolds. My question is does this restriction need to be made? i.e. can you define diffeomorphims between non-real differentiable manifolds?

Comment: What is a "non-real differentiable manifold"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I assume the word 'real' here means that the charts of the manifold go to a real Banach space. So non-real would mean one whose charts go from the manifold to a Banach space which is not based on $\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification There are a couple of things going on here. First of all, it's not clear what it means for a Banach space to be "based on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$". If a real (resp. complex) Banach space $V$ is finite dimensional, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (resp. $\mathbb{C}^{n}$), for some $n < \infty$. If the Banach space is infinite-dimensional it's not clear (to me) what you mean by $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Second, maybe you prefer to work over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. In this case the answer is that complex differentiable is stronger than real differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a notion of differentiable manifold over any complete field (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_field)). As long as you can make sense of what differentiability over a field means you can make sense of a differentiable manifold over that field. You just literally carry over the definitions for the real case.

However in some cases you are more interested in analytic manifolds and the notion of analyticity is usually stronger than differentiability. See [here](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/p-adic-analysis.pdf)
for a treatment of the p-adic case.